# Cannot use axios.delete in ReactJS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, api, axios

My front-end is ReactJS (at port 3000) and my back-end is ROR (at port 3001). I'm trying to delete data by using axios:

```
axios
    .delete('http://localhost:3001/problems/21')
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
```

but It didn't work. I was received the error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3001/problems/21' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I think that is not CORS error, because I used `rack-cors` gem in ROR source, and when I execute method POST or PATCH, they work perfectly. Only my method DELETE does not work.
I also checked the log of ROR and I saw the ROR didn't process when I call method DELETE with axios. Where am I wrong? And what should I do?

Comment: If you only in dev mode you can run browser with react in insecure mode like described here 
 https://alfilatov.com/posts/run-chrome-without-cors/

Comment: Could it be related to headers? Does it work when you try with Postman?